# Subdomain routing to main domain in-spite of virtual host entries in AWS (without Route53)

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtualhost

I have purchased a domain (ex : xyz.com) from GoDaddy. Now I want to point a.xyz.com , b.xyz.com, and xyz.com to 3 subfolders inside my apache www folder in AWS ec2 instance.

I set up 000-default.conf with all the necessary virtual host entries, as well as I tried with different conf files (one per site name, e.g. : a.xyz.com.conf) , I also did a2ensite and apache reload.

One sample config for "a" subdomain. For "b" subdomain its b in place of a.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName a.xyz.com/
    ServerAlias www.a.xyz.com/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/a
    <Directory "/var/www/html/a">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =a.xyz.com/ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.a.xyz.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

But all the sites pointing to same folder content (index.html inside main domain folder). In case of default conf config it picking up the first Vhost entry. In GoDaddy side I mapped (A record) every subdomain to the same elastic IP.

**Without using Route53** how can I achieve the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem just needs another pair of eyes. Even ifnyou wanted to, route 53 would not help - the problem is not in DNS if the browsers find the server

**The ServerName and ServerAlias values should be domain names - not paths**. Remove the '/" from the end - I believe that will fix it.

As an aside, those RewriteRules don't make sense to me. Maybe they need to be removed ?

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a ton. It worked.